# Given a polynomial of degree 5, get minimum and maximum without using derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, optimization, factoring

Given a quintic polynomial (in my case, $x^5+2x^4+16x-32$), I am supposed to get its maximum and minimum value for the interval $I=[-2;2]$ without using the derivative of the corresponing polynomial function.

I remember that for quadratic functions, there was a trick that required you to factor your polynomial and then maximize or minimize all of the factors.

But how would I do this for polynomials of higher degrees?

Comment: This function is continuous in a compact. Then have a max and min. I suppose you want to find that values right ?

Comment: Yes, I do. But then, I would assume that f(-2) and f(2) are minimal/maximal. Can I do that?

Comment: This is only valid for functions f which are increasing. How you know that this is in fact the case ?

Comment: If you prove this then you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
x^5+2x^4+16x-32=(x+2)(x^4+16) - 64
$$
First term is always non-negative on the given interval (hence minimum is attained at $-2$), and increasing, as is easy to show without using derivatives.

Comment: It appears that factoring might always be a good idea. :) Thanks, Marcin!